# Why is the verb “remporter” used twice?

Tags: grammaire

I'd like to find out why the author repeats the same verb in this sentence.

> - Une légende du football qui **avait remporté** le Ballon d’Or à 3 reprises et **remporté** un nombre ahurissant de titres au fil de sa carrière.

Comment: Do you have a link maybe? Considering who is writing/talking, and in what conditions (live brodcast...) it might be just an redundancy mistake.

Comment: [Not considered really nice style](http://www.footmercato.net/autre-championnat/johan-cruyff-disparition-d-une-legende-du-football_174723), a more stylish journalist reporter would have written: *.. qui avait remporté le Ballon d'or à 3 reprises ainsi qu'un nombre ahurissant..*.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "*Une légende du football qui avait remporté le Ballon d’Or à 3 reprises et remporté un nombre ahurissant de titres au fil de sa carrière.*" is correct.

The sentence "*Une légende du football qui avait remporté le Ballon d’Or à 3 reprises et un nombre ahurissant de titres au fil de sa carrière.*" is also true.

It's a bit strange in English but totally common in French. Repeating twice a verb after a "and" is not considered a mistake.